# How to replace sys/sem.h functionality when porting to Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

Hey guys I am porting an application from Linux to Android by using Android Studio and NDK. I did my research and it looks like I am going to have a problem down the road. The problem is that Android does not support `sys/sem.h` calls, in other words semaphore functionality.

Would you be able to give me an advice how I could overcome this problem? Moreover, I have notice that Android offers "Android Binders", is there any way I could use this functionality to solve my problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.